# How to specify a style not to be overriden by styles specified in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got some elements whose style is dynamically modified by a JS. However, I hope one of which would not be modified.

How could I specify its style, which is static, not to be overriden anyway. Thanks.

Comment: You mean style attribute or style rules in an external CSS? Or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen, you can't do this in CSS; however, you can instruct your JavaScript to not update an element's style, but it requires some manual attention.  Consider the following:

HTML

```
<ul id="some-list">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li class="no-style-update">C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript (vanilla)

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("some-list").getElementsByTagName("LI");

for ( var i=0, l=nodes.length; i<l; ++i ) {
    // If style updates are allowed
    if ( !nodes[i].className.match(/\bno-style-update\b/i) ) {
        // Update the element's style
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this cannot be done. JavaScript executes after the CSS has been loaded & applied. you'll have to change your IDs & classes and/or your JavaScript code so that it does not target the elements you don't want changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The best you could do would be to override the javascript methods that do the modifying.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't.  CSS is applied as it is encountered by the browser. Since the call to the JavaScript is the latest call that changes that particular style, it will be applied to the element.

What you can to is to run another JavaScript that changes the style of that specific element after the first script. Since there is something unique about that element, you can probably refer to it by its ID, class, or name.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could put the elements into an iframe, where the src attribute refers to a different path or domain. The javascript in the container page then couldn't modify the element, because of same origin rule which doesn't allow modification of data from different origins.